# Class extends Uint8Array, how to return Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this custom simple class:

```
class U8a extends Uint8Array {
  logMe() {
    return this.subarray(0);
  }
}
```

And I ran this code:

```
const u = new U8a([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(u.logMe());
```

Expected result:

```
Uint8Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Actual result:

```
U8a [Uint8Array] [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Is it possible to return the result as an Uint8Array only?

Comment: Are you sure this is a typescript, not merely javascript question?

Comment: What is the problem  `u instanceof Uint8Array  => true` you just extend so the u is Uint8Array   object

Comment: @malbarmawi Now I can do `u.logMe().logMe()`. I want to disable this.

Comment: Why would you expect `Uint8Array`? That's not what it is: "The `subarray()` method returns a new `TypedArray` on the same `ArrayBuffer` store and with the same element types as for this `TypedArray` object." Plus it'd make your logging *explicitly* incorrect. You could use `#from` and create a new array.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, that's what I expected too. Hence this question, the title translates to: is it possible to actually return an Uint8Array on the same ArrayBuffer store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `logMe` method to return new instant of `Uint8Array` so will not have the logMe method.

```
class U8a extends Uint8Array {
  logMe() {
    return new Uint8Array(this.entries());
  }
}

const u = new U8a([1, 2, 3]);
const u2 = u.logMe();
console.log(u2.logMe()); throw Uncaught TypeError: u2.logMe is not a function
```